# LINQ Multiple Column Join

Tags: linq, join, left-join, multiple-columns

Our initial query is composed of numerous subqueries that work correctly, based on joins that use a single column (productId). The resulting model maps to a grid that lists product names along with their respective required quantities for yesterday, today and tomorrow.

However, a requirement was received for an additional differentiator based on the age of the product and therefore it was necessary to modify the original query.

So, the following code is a modification of working code that uses a single field, the ProductId as the key. In attempting to modify the query to use a multiple column key (ProductId and Age) I ran into trouble, receiving the following error:

> ***The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'.***

In the preceding query that creates Distinct Aggregate, I changed the key to composite of ProductId and age and assign a new memeber of the anonymous type, **productKey** to a **new { pr.productId, pr.age }**. Then in the final query, I am trying to join this result **on productKey equals new { y.productId, y.age }** (y representing the joining result "yesterday").

When I hover over each of the keys of the joined results (gr.productKey and y.productKey), the following is displayed for each:

> **'b 'a.productKey**
>
> **Anonymous Types:**
>
> **'a is new {'b productKey, int productId, string age,... }**
>
> **'b is new {int productId, string age}**

Since both are of type **'b** a **new {int productId, string age}** I was expecting success; however, the compiler continues to be uncooperative. I am trusting that one **new {int,string}** is the same as another regarless of the names.

```
 var yesterday = from p in productOrdered
                 where p.deliveryDate.Date == DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date
                 group p by new { p.id, p.age } into g
                 orderby g.Key
                 select new {
                     productKey = g.Key,
                     productId = g.Max(s => s.id),
                     age = g.Max(s => s.age),
                     quantity = g.Count(),
                     weight = g.Sum(s => s.weight), 
                 };

 var grp = (from pr in prods2
            group pr by new { pr.productId, pr.age } into g
            orderby g.Key
            select new {
                productKey = g.Key,
                productId = g.Max(s => s.productId),
                age = g.Max(s => s.age),
                code = g.Max(s => s.code),
                product = g.Max(s => s.product),
                uom = g.Max(s => s.uom)
            }).Distinct();

var model = from gr in grp
            join y in yesterday on gr.productKey equals new { y.productId, y.age } into outer0
            from y in outer0.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join n in now on gr.productKey equals new { n.productId, n.age } into outer1
            from n in outer1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join t in tomorrow on gr.productKey equals new { t.productId, t.age } into outer2
            from t in outer2.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new RequiredProductsViewModel
            {
                ProductId = gr.productId,
                Aged = gr.age,
                Code = gr.code.ToString(),
                Description = gr.product.ToString(),
                MinusQ = (!(null == y) ? y.quantity : 0),
                MinusW = (!(null == y) ? decimal.Parse(y.weight.ToString()) : 0),
                ZeroQ = (!(null == n) ? n.quantity : 0),
                ZeroW = (!(null == n) ? decimal.Parse(n.weight.ToString()) : 0),
                OneQ = (!(null == t) ? t.quantity : 0),
                OneW = (!(null == t) ? decimal.Parse(t.weight.ToString()) : 0),
                UofM = gr.uom.ToString()
            };
```

Testing in LINQPad resulted in similar results and I also tried several variations based on similar questions on this site such as but not limited to the following:

> join y in yesterday on **new {Key1 = gr.productId,Key2 = gr.age} equals y.productKey** into outer0
>
> join y in yesterday on **new { gr.productId, gr.age }** equals y.productKey into outer0

Again, the original query that this modification is bsed on works successfully. I am pretty sure that this is one of those "a little knowlege, is a dangerous thing" issues. Or maybe just "little knowledge" issue. Either way, I am hoping that the LINQ Gods can see a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try declare named type for multiple column key instead of using anonymous:

```
public class ProductKey
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public int ProductAge { get; set; }
}
```

Use this ProductKey in "group by" and "join" clauses.
So your queries will look like:

```
               var yesterday = from p in productOrdered
                 where p.deliveryDate.Date == DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date
                 group p by new ProductKey { ProductId=p.id, ProductAge=p.age } into g
                 orderby g.Key.ProductId
                 select new {
                     productKey = g.Key,
                     productId = g.Max(s => s.id),
                     age = g.Max(s => s.age),
                     quantity = g.Count(),
                     weight = g.Sum(s => s.weight), 
                 };

 var grp = (from pr in prods2
            group pr by new ProductKey{ ProductId=pr.productId, ProductKey=pr.age } into g
            orderby g.Key.ProductId
            select new {
                productKey = g.Key,
                productId = g.Max(s => s.productId),
                age = g.Max(s => s.age),
                code = g.Max(s => s.code),
                product = g.Max(s => s.product),
                uom = g.Max(s => s.uom)
            }).Distinct();

var model = from gr in grp
            join y in yesterday on gr.productKey equals new ProductKey { ProductId=y.productId, ProductAge=y.age } into outer0
            from y in outer0.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join n in now on gr.productKey equals new ProductKey { ProductId=n.productId, ProductAge=n.age } into outer1
            from n in outer1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join t in tomorrow on gr.productKey equals new ProductKey { ProductId=t.productId, ProductAge=t.age } into outer2
            from t in outer2.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new RequiredProductsViewModel
            {
                ProductId = gr.productId,
                Aged = gr.age,
                Code = gr.code.ToString(),
                Description = gr.product.ToString(),
                MinusQ = (!(null == y) ? y.quantity : 0),
                MinusW = (!(null == y) ? decimal.Parse(y.weight.ToString()) : 0),
                ZeroQ = (!(null == n) ? n.quantity : 0),
                ZeroW = (!(null == n) ? decimal.Parse(n.weight.ToString()) : 0),
                OneQ = (!(null == t) ? t.quantity : 0),
                OneW = (!(null == t) ? decimal.Parse(t.weight.ToString()) : 0),
                UofM = gr.uom.ToString()
            };
```

**UPDATE:**

The ORDER BY clause with ProductKey class will give an error (linq does not know how to order multiple column class) so you should order by g.Key.ProductId specifically

Comment: When I make the above changes, I get an error stating "At least one object must implement IComparable." This shows up in all of the above queries, "yesterday", "grp" and "model", as well as those queries not shown ("now" and "tomorrow") but are the same as the query "yesterday".

Comment: @user946045: IComparable defines CompareTo method that tells how to compare two instances of the class. It is required for ordering, but in this case I think, it would be better to order by specific column - aswer updated

Comment: Well so far, creating a productKey class, seems like taking 2 steps backwards. When I use an anonymous type for all the queries preceding the last, I get accurate results at each step. When I use a defined class, I get a IComparable error, an in no case am I using an Order By clause.

Comment: @user946045: IComparable error occurs even without orderby? You had orderby clause in "yesterday" and "grp" query. Could you post your current query?

Comment: Thanks. Wow, I must be blind or perhaps it was just the 4AM factor. So let me test a few things first and then post again.

Answer (score 0):

The following changes appear to have produced the required result.

1. In the dependent queries grouping was changed to **new { p.id, p.ageId}**
2. All orderby clauses were revised from a single orderby based on **g.Key** to 2 separate orderby clauses based on **g.Key.id** and **g.Key.ageId**
3. Finally, in the query defining the *Left* table, I used the following:

> group **new { pr.code, pr.product, pr.uom}** by **new { pr.productId, pr.ageId}** into g

I had used this variation successfully before in another method but have forgotten where I came across it. It certainly defines the fields and composite key precisely.

This method now produces an aggregate list of ordered products with totals of their quantities and weights. In addition, products with different age requirements are listed separately. Ultimately, we get a product list that shows only those products that have been ordered, grouped by age and showing quantities and weights, for orders past due, orders for today and orders for tomorrow.

I have included the all of the code for this method as both an aid to some and a challenge for those with greater skills to find improvements.

```
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult AjaxOps_ActionList() {

        var orders = salesOrderHeaderRepository.All.ToArray();
        var details = salesOrderDetailRepository.All.ToArray();
        var ages = ageRepository.All.ToArray();
        var custAges = customerAgeRepository.All.ToArray();
        var kinds = foodKindRepository.All.ToArray();
        var types = foodTypeRepository.All.ToArray();
        var units = unitOfMeasureRepository.All.ToArray();

        var products = from p in productRepository.All.ToArray()
                       select new {
                           productId = p.ProductId,
                           code = p.Name,
                           typeId = p.TypeId,
                           kindId = p.KindId,
                           Description = p.Description,
                           unitId = p.UnitId,
                           weight = (p == null) ? 0 : p.AverageWeight
                       };

        var productOrdered = from o in orders
                             join d in details on o.SalesOrderHeaderId equals d.SalesOrderId
                             join c in custAges on o.CustomerId equals c.CustomerId
                             join a in ages on c.AgeId equals a.AgeId
                             join p in products on d.ProductId equals p.productId
                             select new {
                                 id = d.ProductId,
                                 code = p.code,
                                 ageId = a.AgeId,
                                 quantity = (null == d) ? 0 : d.Quantity,
                                 weight = ((null == d) ? 0 : d.Quantity) * ((null == p) ? 0 : p.weight),
                                 deliveryDate = o.DeliveryDateTime
                             };

        var tomorrow = from p in productOrdered
                       where p.deliveryDate.Date == DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date
                       group p by new { p.id, p.ageId} into g
                       orderby g.Key.id
                       orderby g.Key.ageId
                       select new {
                           productId = g.Key.id,
                           ageId = g.Key.ageId,
                           quantity = g.Count(),
                           weight = g.Sum(s => s.weight)
                       };

        var now = from p in productOrdered
                  where p.deliveryDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date
                  group p by new { p.id, p.ageId } into g
                  orderby g.Key.id
                  orderby g.Key.ageId
                  select new {
                      productId = g.Key.id,
                      ageId = g.Key.ageId,
                      quantity = g.Count(),
                      weight = g.Sum(s => s.weight)
                  };

        var yesterday = from p in productOrdered
                        where p.deliveryDate.Date == DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date
                        group p by new { p.id, p.ageId } into g
                        orderby g.Key.id
                        orderby g.Key.ageId
                        select new {
                            productId = g.Key.id,
                            ageId = g.Key.ageId,
                            quantity = g.Count(),
                            weight = g.Sum(s => s.weight)
                        };

        var prods = from pr in products
                    join p in productOrdered on pr.productId equals p.id
                    join t in types on pr.typeId equals t.FoodTypeId
                    join k in kinds on pr.kindId equals k.FoodKindId
                    join u in units on pr.unitId equals u.AUnitMeasureId
                    select new {
                        productId = pr.productId,
                        ageId = p.ageId,
                        code = pr.code,
                        product = t.Name + " " + k.Name + " " + pr.Description,
                        uom = u.Name
                    };

        var grp = (from pr in prods
                  group new { pr.code, pr.product, pr.uom} by new { pr.productId, pr.ageId} into g
                  orderby g.Key.productId
                  orderby g.Key.ageId
                  select new {
                      productKey = g.Key,
                      productId = g.Key.productId,
                      ageId = g.Key.ageId,
                      code = g.Max(s => s.code),
                      product = g.Max(s => s.product),
                      uom = g.Max(s => s.uom)
                  }).Distinct();

        var model = from gr in grp
                    join y in yesterday on gr.productKey equals new { y.productId, y.ageId } into outer0
                    from y in outer0.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join n in now on gr.productKey equals new { n.productId, n.ageId } into outer1
                    from n in outer1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join t in tomorrow on gr.productKey equals new { t.productId, t.ageId } into outer2
                    from t in outer2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new RequiredProductsViewModel
                    {
                        ProductId = gr.productId,
                        Code = gr.code.ToString(),
                        Description = gr.product.ToString(),
                        AgeId = gr.ageId,
                        MinusQ = (!(null == y) ? y.quantity : 0),
                        MinusW = (!(null == y) ? decimal.Parse(y.weight.ToString()) : 0),
                        ZeroQ = (!(null == n) ? n.quantity : 0),
                        ZeroW = (!(null == n) ? decimal.Parse(n.weight.ToString()) : 0),
                        OneQ = (!(null == t) ? t.quantity : 0),
                        OneW = (!(null == t) ? decimal.Parse(t.weight.ToString()) : 0),
                        UofM = gr.uom.ToString()
                    };

        return View(new GridModel<RequiredProductsViewModel>
        {
            Data = model
        });
```

Most likely there will be other (and perhaps better) solutions; however, this is working and that's my story and I'm sticking to it.

A final thanks to PanJanek fortaking the time to make suggestions. Please let me know if you find any way to improve upon this.